# Анализ временных рядов нейросетью

Tags: javascript, нейронные-сети, анализ-данных

Способна ли библиотека решить следующую задачу (вычислительную задачу)?

Даны ежедневные данные (x1,x2,x3), данные по декадам (x4) и единожды заданные данные (x5, x6). Данные собираются за полугодие. В конце полугодия получается y1. Собраны данные за несколько лет.

Пример - гостиница. Постояльцы платят ежедневно (номера разного размера - плата разная - x1, x2). Ежедневно начисляется заработная плата работникам - x3. Раз в десять дней закупаются продукты питания и вода - x4. Раз в полгода оплачиваются коммунальные счета, делается ремонт - x5, x6 (для упрощения считаем, что это происходит в начале интервала). Раз в полгода делается финансовый отчет и вычисляется прибыль - y1.

Проблема в том что нужно предсказать y1 до окончания полугодия в произвольный день.

П.С.
Я склоняюсь к LSTM. И надеюсь, что все данные можно свести к минимальному интервалу (день, в данном примере) - считать все X ежедневными. Но у меня не получается понять как подать числовые данные в сеть.

И да - мне нужно не классифицировать входные данные, а обсчитывать их в сети...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример данных:

```
{
  ...
  2018_1: { ... },
  2018_2: { ... },
  2019_1: {
    rent1: [19200,19200,19200,19200,12000,12000,7200,15600,15600,7200,7200,8400,7200,8400,8400,8400,10800,21600,21600,21600,21600,19200,15600,7200,7200,8400,7200,8400],
    rent2: [19800,18000,18000,18000,14400,12600,12600,12600,14400,14400,14400,9000,18000,18000,18000,19800,19800,12600,18000,18000,18000,14400,14400,14400,14400,14400,14400,14400],
    salary: [-9000,-9000,-9000,-9000,-8400,-8400,-7700,-8400,-8400,-7700,-7700,-7700,-7700,-8000,-8000,-8000,-8400,-8600,-9000,-9000,-9000,-8600,-8600,-7700,-7700,-7700,-7700,-7700],
    food: [-27743,-32682,-23009.5],
    repair: [-47000],
    annuity: [-175000]
    profitability: 266765.5
  }
}
```

Если привести данные в одномерную форму - нейросеть (brain.NeuralNetwork) выполняет вычисления. Но только в конце периода. Прогноз необходим в любое время периода - т.е. до окончания серии данные в текущем периоде. Размеры данных могут варьироваться - високосный год, неожиданные ремонты, бонусы сотрудникам, испорченные продукты и т.п. Я думаю, что для этого требуется сеть с памятью (возможно какая-то из brain.recurrent.*). Но я не понимаю, как передать в неё даже простые тестовые данные что бы она выполнила расчет.

Возможно, более понятным будет другой пример: прогнозирование урожайности: ежедневные погодные данные, внесение удобрений перед посевом, обработка от вредителей и др. - суть в том, что данные представляются временными рядами разного периода прежде чем станет известен результат (погода получается ежедневно с момента сева, но урожай собирается только в конце года).

Суть моего вопроса в том как с пеомощью нейронной сети с памятью выполнять прогноз по не полному временному ряду данных (при том что сеть должна обучаться по временным рядам данных).

Comment: Вопрос: выбор в качестве инструмента нейросети-ограничение учебной задачи  или ваш добровольный выбор? Просто в решении таких задач (прогноз по временным рядам) обычно задействуют методы анализа Time Series.Там есть подходы для анализа сезонностей, трендов и пр. Результат-интерпретируемый. Применение НС требует на много больше обучающих примеров-они у вас есть? И получаем обычно неинтерпретируемый ответ, что не есть здорово, особенно в финансовых задачах. Eще вопрос - не понятна ваша ремарка "нужно не классифицировать входные данные"- как он влияет на выбор решения? И причем тут javascript?

Comment: Требуется использовать именно нейронную сеть, причем в браузере. Я привел лишь фрагмент обучающего набора, что бы пояснить структура данных которую предстоит обработать - имеются данные за несколько лет и по нескольким объектам. Спасибо за замечание с ремаркой - нейросеть, в данной задаче, нужна как универсальный вычислитель - предсказать результат длительного процесса на любой его стадии (обычно же нейросети используются для классификации объектов оценки по группам, например поиска чего-то на изображениях - потому я и сделал это замечание).

Comment: @passant литературу по анализу Time Series (с сериями имеющими разные периоды) подскажите? Может пригодится когда.